# Returning output of linprog in Matlab as a sparse vector

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

I am using `mu=linprog(f,A,b, Aeq, beq)` in Matlab by passing `A,b, Aeq, beq` as sparse matrices because they are huge, e.g.,`A` has dimension `2000 x 2000`

Matlab doesn't give me any memory error but it takes quite long to run the linear programming (as expected, given the big sizes).

One thing that I have noticed is that, despite I pass `A,b, Aeq, beq` as sparse, the output `mu` is returned as non-sparse. Could returning `mu` as a sparse vector help saving some time (and memory)? Why `linprog` does not do that? How could I modify `linprog` to force that?

---

This is my specific example (you can see that by constraints each element of `mu` is `0` or `1` and `mu` is sparse)

```
n_m=10;
n_w=15;
C=n_m*n_w+n_m+n_w;

%Inequalities A*mu<=b
b=sparse(C,1);
i=1:1:C;
v1=-ones(1,C);
A=sparse(i,i,v1,C,C);


%Equalities Aeq*mu=beq

row1=kron(1:1:n_m, ones(1,n_w+1)); 
temp=zeros(n_w+1, n_m);
for i=1:n_m
    temp(:,i)=(i:n_m:n_m*n_w+i).'; 
end
column1=temp(:).'; 
v1=ones(1,n_m*n_w+n_m);
Aeqmen=sparse(row1, column1, v1, n_m, C); 


row2=kron(1:1:n_w, ones(1,n_m+1)); 
temp=zeros(n_m+1,n_w);
for j=1:n_w
    temp(:,j)=[(j-1)*n_m+1:j*n_m n_m*n_w+n_m+j].';
end
column2=temp(:).'; 
v2=ones(1,n_m*n_w+n_w);
Aeqwomen=sparse(row2, column2, v2, n_w, C); 

Aeq=[Aeqmen; Aeqwomen]; 
beq=ones(n_m+n_w,1); 

%Objective function
f=-(randn(n_m*n_w+n_m+n_w,1));  %Cx1

%LP
mu= linprog(f,A,b, Aeq, beq); %Cx1
```

---

**EDIT**
Thanks to some comments/answers below, I found that, **for my specific example**,`intlinprog` is much faster than `linprog`. This can be seen by running this for example:

```
clear
N=100:100:500;
mu1=cell(size(N,2),1);
mu2=cell(size(N,2),1);
rng default

for n=1:size(N,2)
n_m=N(n);
n_w=N(n);
C=n_m*n_w+n_m+n_w;

%Inequalities A*mu<=b
b=zeros(C,1);
i=1:1:C;
v1=-ones(1,C);
A=sparse(i,i,v1,C,C);


%Equalities Aeq*mu=beq
row1=kron(1:1:n_m, ones(1,n_w+1)); 
temp=zeros(n_w+1, n_m);
for i=1:n_m
    temp(:,i)=(i:n_m:n_m*n_w+i).'; 
end
column1=temp(:).'; 
v1=ones(1,n_m*n_w+n_m);
Aeqmen=sparse(row1, column1, v1, n_m, C); 

row2=kron(1:1:n_w, ones(1,n_m+1)); 
temp=zeros(n_m+1,n_w);
for j=1:n_w
    temp(:,j)=[(j-1)*n_m+1:j*n_m n_m*n_w+n_m+j].';
end
column2=temp(:).'; 
v2=ones(1,n_m*n_w+n_w);
Aeqwomen=sparse(row2, column2, v2, n_w, C); 

Aeq=[Aeqmen; Aeqwomen]; 
beq=ones(n_m+n_w,1); 

%Objective function
f=-(randn(n_m*n_w+n_m+n_w,1));  %Cx1

%Intcon
intcon=1:1:C; 

tic
mu1{n}= linprog(f,A,b, Aeq, beq); %Cx1
toc
tic
mu2{n}= intlinprog(f,intcon,A,b, Aeq, beq); %Cx1
toc
end
```

Comment: A sparse matrix saves a lot of space (and time). A sparse vector does not so much. I would not bother.

Comment: Thanks, but for large `C` (`C` in my example is the dimension of `mu`), Matlab does not even allow to store `mu` unless it is sparse.

Comment: I don't understand. If `A = 2000 x 2000` (which is small btw. -- nowadays we solve problems with millions of rows and columns) then mu is a vector of length 2000. Not big at all..

Comment: `linprog` is not a good LP solver. I think the sparsity is not the issue. The implementation of `linprog` is. If you look around you can find comparable (maybe better) free solvers. Check CLP or GLPK for example. If you have an academic affiliation use Gurobi or CPLEX for sure, which are free for academic use. They should have a MATLAB interface. A better thing to do is to avoid MATLAB also, but that's a different story.

Comment: @Pooya From reading http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.5/examples/linprog_m.html, I thought `linprogr`  in Matlab 2017 already implemented Gurobi, Am I wrong? I am new to Gurobi, apologies if my question is no sense.

Comment: BTW have you tried the interior point version of `linprog` instead of the simplex method? And no: `linprog` is not based on `Gurobi`.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I have tried `intlinprogr` and it is much faster than `linprog` (even with interior point version) for my example.

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen a MIP being faster than an LP (and I am doing this for a very long time).

Comment: Thank you @ErwinKalvelagen. I don't know why, I am not an expert, I have added to my question  a piece of code that seems to highlight that for my specific example `intlinprog` is actually faster.

Comment: @user3285148 that seems to be a Gurobi interface in MATLAB that uses the same set of inputs and outputs, so you can easily use it in MATLAB after you download Gurobi. Also, these benchmarks (for the simplex solvers) may help: http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/lpsimp.html. From the geometric mean of runtimes, it looks like CLP performs so well that is even comparable to the commercial solvers. But again, CPLEX, Gurobi and Xpress are the best.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a system of equations (Ax=b or variations) with sparse matrices does not need (and in the vast majority of the cases is not) sparse.

E.g.

- Finite element methods (the system matrix is sparse, yet the
  underlying physic result is generally not)
- Most types of tomography

Comment: Thanks. In my case, the output is sparse. I have added an example. Thank you. Is there any easy way I can modify the `linprog` function to get a sparse output?

Comment: @user3285148 still, you can not ensure it is, as depends on the numerical result. It just happens to be sparse

Comment: @user3285148 hum for some reason now it does.

Answer (score 0):

While it's typical for equality and inequality constraints to be sparse in linear programming formulations, that doesn't necessarily imply that the resulting solution will be sparse (in fact, in general it will not be for an LP unless constraints specifically require it).

It could be more common in a MIP to see sparsely-populated solutions if the integer constraints force a lot of outputs to zero (for instance, if you have a lot of decision variables that are constrained to be <= 1 and a coupling constraint on total capacity, this may dictate that the vast majority of decision variables will be exactly zero).  In an equivalent LP (also known as a "relaxation" of the MIP problem since the LP effectively relaxes integer constraints) you'd be more likely to get lots of small, non-integer values for the decision variables.

The function linprog is a function in the optimization package provided by Matlab, so it's unlikely that you can modify it directly (and this would probably not be a good idea).

You might want to inspect your results to find out how many of the outputs are exactly zero - that would tell you if a sparse solution is even in the cards for this problem:

```
% Total number of entries that are nonzero
nnz(D)
% Density of the matrix relative to total number of elements
nnz(D)/prod(size(D))
```

Comment: `nnz(D)` is better, then you just check the size. In general a better method is to calculate the sparsity: `nnz(D)/prod(size(D))`

Comment: Wow - used Matlab for 20 years and have never come across nnz.  Will update answer to include.

Comment: Thanks for your insights: (1) I think my LP can be rewritten as a MIP (the constraints ensure that each element of `mu` is `0` or `1`); I  know `intlinprog` in Matlab but it seems that `b` and `beq` cannot  be passed as sparse; (2) in my LP, the output `mu` is sparse by constraints (it can have at most a fixed number of ones that depends on `n_m` and `n_w`)

Comment: Using a MIP instead of an LP to save memory does not make sense at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: I’m not advocating use of MIP as a memory-saving approach, just illustrating diff between LP and MIP and noting that LP will not generally result in sparse decision variables.